# Add values to a list contains a Lookup Field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list named "Designation" that contains a Designation Code and Designation Name.
I have another list named "Employee" that contains Employee Name and Designation Name (as a Lookup Field).
I am able to insert values to "Employee" list using the following code.

```
    protected void AddEmp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string emp_name = txtEmployeeName.Text;
      string emp_designation = ddlDesignation.SelectedValue;                    
      using (SPSite site = new SPSite("My Site"))
      {
       using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
       {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
         web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
         SPList splist_employees = web.Lists["Employee"];
         SPList splist_designations = web.Lists["Designations"];
         SPListItemCollection splc_items = splist_employees.Items;
         SPListItem spli_item = splc_items.Add();
         SPFieldLookup lookup = splist_employees.Fields["Designated"] as SPFieldLookup;
         string fieldName = lookup.LookupField;
         spli_item["Employee Name"] = emp_name;
         spli_item[fieldName] = GetLookFieldIDS(emp_designation, splist_designations);
         spli_item.Update();
         });
        }
      }
    }

    public static string GetLookFieldIDS(string lookupValues, SPList lookupSourceList)
    {
     string id = string.Empty;
     SPFieldLookupValueCollection lookupIds = new SPFieldLookupValueCollection();
     SPQuery query = new Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery();
     query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Designation' /><Value type='Text'>"+lookupValues + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
     SPListItemCollection listItems = lookupSourceList.GetItems(query);
     foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem item in listItems)
     {
      id = item.ID.ToString();
     }
     return id;
    }
```

Here I have given the field name as 'Designation' inside the query.

But, I want to find the field name based on the value given from the user end instead of hard-coding the field name as 'Designation'.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just add a dropdown for all of the field names and build your CAML based on those selections.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your request but, you could pass [SPFieldLookup.LookupField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.lookupfield) property to your GetLookFieldIDS method and use that variable instead of "Designation"

```
spli_item[fieldName] = GetLookFieldIDS(emp_designation, splist_designations, lookup.LookupField);
```